# How to set up Grafana notifications?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating

Good afternoon.
There is Grafana 10 version. Installed Grafana Image Render. Through Share, the board displays correctly.

But how do I properly compose a notification template? By default it looks like this:
`Value: B=89.54487298398345, C=1
Labels:

- alertname = Алерт1
- grafana_folder = Folder_one
- instance = 10.10.1.3:9182
- job = ServerOne
  Annotations:
  Silence: http://localhost:3000/alerting/silence/new?alertmanager=`

I need something like this:

Alert
Host
Meaning
Schedule

I tried to write manually, as a result it was displayed
 АЛАРМ: TestAlert

Status:

- B: